# Extend the user profile django 1.5 but retain Django's admin.py format

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've been playing around with extending Django's User model which I haven't attempted since pre 1.5, so I'm trying to get back up to speed with things.

Finally getting it to work, I want to ensure that User is still accessible through the admin site, however it now seems that when you extend it, the user model disappears from the admin site, unless you call for your own auth model to be registered.  My question is, is there a way to call the custom auth model whilst maintaining the same formatting from `django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explicitly possible in Django 1.5+, by subclassing `AbstractBaseUser` and setting `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to point to your model. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).